# Drop down menu not aligning

Tags: css

My drop down menu is not aligning. Also, it is constantly showing dark yellow, the color it's only supposed to show when I am hovering on it.

Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction

```
  <div class="top">

  </div> 

  <div class="white_line"></div>

  <div id="navi li"> 
    <ul id="navi">
      <li id="navi01">
          <div class="dropdown">
               <a href="index.html">STARTSEITE</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <ul>
                  <li><a href="homoeopathie.html">HOM&Ouml;OPATHIE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="wirbelsaeulentherapie.html">WIRBELS&Auml;ULEN-</b>BEHANDLUNG</li>
                  </ul>
                  </div> 
             </div>        
       </li>    
       <li id="navi02"><a href="uebermich.html">&Uuml;BER MICH</a></li>




   </ul>
  </div>
```

Thanks
Anu

Comment: where is css code

Comment: write your css code or give a link for your css code

Comment: The problem is that you have no CSS code... :,-D

Comment: looks like he is using bootstrap